# Why I cannot import the python3 package I have created despite being properly installed?

Tags: python, pip

I have created my first python package within test.pypi (developed within python3.7.1, for further details: https://github.com/BatLabLancaster/preparenovonix):
https://test.pypi.org/project/preparenovonix/

This can be installed properly by: `python3 -m pip`

However when I try to import the package I get an error message.

I have tried installing the package in Windows and Linux. I've also used a Docker container with ubuntu and python3.6. In all the 3 environments I tried the installation was succesful. For the installation, I followed the description in https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/packaging-projects/. Below I show the installation command and the meassage I get in docker+ubuntu (similar message in Windows):

```
$ python3 -m pip install -i https://test.pypi.org/simple/ --user preparenovonix 

Collecting preparenovonix
  Using cached https://test-files.pythonhosted.org/packages/1b/b2/97dd3a537bae2b9605c5e1435c49ac644946b10adf41dc904dee2f1d45e4/preparenovonix-0.0.1-py3-none-any.whl
Installing collected packages: preparenovonix
Successfully installed preparenovonix-0.0.1
```

This is the error message I get when importing it:

```
# python3 -i
Python 3.6.7 (default, Oct 22 2018, 11:32:17)
[GCC 8.2.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import preparenovonix
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'preparenovonix'
```

I expected python to be able to see the package given that it was successfuly installed and it shows also when using pip show.

Comment: What's your package structure look like? Your published package name may not match your python package name.

Comment: I'm on mobile, so don't have the tools to look through the downloaded tar.gz

Comment: There isn't any any module or package `preparenovonix` in the source code.

Comment: you need to change your package structure and keep the whole package `preparenovonix` n same directory level as setup.py

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is a problem with the package structure. I tried your "example.py" and it worked.

```
D:\preparenovonix>python
Python 3.7.3 (v3.7.3:ef4ec6ed12, Mar 25 2019, 22:22:05) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import pycode.novonix_add
>>>
```